# UIWebview in flashDevelop

Tags: ios, mobile, uiwebview, air, flashdevelop

I'm fixing an app originally done in FlashDevelop, and trying to use darkredz UIWebView script to load an external website. My code isn't much different from the code used in the tutorial found here: http://darkredz.com/tutorial-on-uiwebview-native-extension/. Problem is that it's failing without providing any error messages. Nothing will display, and the FINISH_LOAD event listener that I set up is not being triggered. I haven't found anything online about the issue other than the documentation page, and this tutorial. Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: considering that darkredz is offline now, I think u should find a replacement. we have recently released a new ANE, Rich WebView and you can find it here: http://myappsnippet.com/webview-ane/